# Update multiple second Id's to match the first Id's of a series

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is a subset of data I have:

```
|Id1|Id2|
---------
|100| 90|
|101| 90|
|102| 90|
|217|101|
|218|101|
|219|101|
```

But Id2 should match the first occurrence of each separate occurrence of Id1, whenever Id2 changes, like this:

```
|Id1|Id2|
---------
|100|100|
|101|100|
|102|100|
|217|217|
|218|217|
|219|217|
```

How can I change this in thousands of rows with an update statement?

Thanks for your help, this was difficult to explain!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  (SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something else?)

Comment: Sorry, just updated the tags, I'm using SQL server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `CTE` with usage of [**`FIRST_VALUE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx):

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT Id1, Id2,
          FIRST_VALUE(Id1) OVER (PARTITION BY Id2 ORDER BY Id1) AS newValue
   FROM mytable
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Id2 = newValue
```

Well, unfortunately `FIRST_VALUE` isn't available in SQL Server 2008. In this case you can use the following query:

```
;WITH CTE_Rn AS (
   SELECT Id1, Id2,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id2 ORDER BY Id1) AS rn
   FROM mytable
), ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT t1.Id1, t2.Id2, t2.Id1 AS newValue
   FROM mytable AS t1
   JOIN CTE_Rn AS t2 ON t1.Id2 = t2.Id2 AND t2.rn = 1
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Id2 = newValue
```

Comment: This works great on the new development server with the new SQL Server as I can use FIRST_VALUE.
Unfortunately the alternative runs, but doesn't update the values.

Comment: @Fizzgig I've tested it before posting. Can you add a test case so that I can reproduce the error that you get?

Comment: What information do you need? (Sorry, I'm new here)

Comment: @Fizzgig When used with the sample data provided in the OP the second query produces the correct result. Can you add some other sample data demonstrating a failure of the second query?